# nodejs sequelize include relation sorting

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

ha ve tow models one is Boat Master and another is boat price I want all boat data with its price and order by descending boat price the query is not working as expected its sorting data inside my relation and also the result is shown is sorted but its not picking up the boat who has price highest among all boats

```
db.BoatMaster.findAndCountAll({
    distinct: true,
    limit:request.params.pagesize,
    offset:offsetpage,
    attributes:[
        'id',
        'name',
        'saleprice','length','cabins','year','berths','createdAt','updatedAt'
    ],
    include:[
        "boat_price",

    ],
    order:[
        ['boat_price','price','DESC']
    ],
})
```

and here is the query output

```
SELECT 
  "BoatMaster".*, 
  "boat_price"."id" AS "boat_price.id", 
  "boat_price"."price" AS "boat_price.price", 
  "boat_price"."boatId" AS "boat_price.boatId", 
  "boat_price"."currency" AS "boat_price.currency", 
  "boat_price"."datefrom" AS "boat_price.datefrom", 
  "boat_price"."dateto" AS "boat_price.dateto" 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      "BoatMaster"."id", 
      "BoatMaster"."name", 
      "BoatMaster"."saleprice", 
      "BoatMaster"."length", 
      "BoatMaster"."cabins", 
      "BoatMaster"."year", 
      "BoatMaster"."berths", 
      "BoatMaster"."createdAt", 
      "BoatMaster"."updatedAt" 
    FROM 
      "BoatMasters" AS "BoatMaster" 
    WHERE 
      (
        SELECT 
          "boatId" 
        FROM 
          "boatprices" AS "boat_price" 
        WHERE 
          (
            "boat_price"."boatId" = "BoatMaster"."id"
          ) 
        LIMIT 
          1
      ) IS NOT NULL 
    LIMIT 
      10 OFFSET 0
  ) AS "BoatMaster" 
  INNER JOIN "boatprices" AS "boat_price" ON "BoatMaster"."id" =     "boat_price"."boatId" 
ORDER BY 
  "boat_price"."price" DESC;
```

can anyone help me out what I am doing wrong here because data is not sorting according to the price?
thank in advanced

Answer (score 0):

try this (if correct):

```
 include:[
        boat_price,

    ],
    order:[
        [boat_price,'price','DESC']
    ],
```

or

```
 include:[
        boat_price,

    ],
    order:[
        ['boat_price.price','DESC']
    ],
```

Comment: last if correct . try 
```
order:[ [ 'price', 'DESC'] ],
```